# (Lua 5.1) How to convert a string to a function

Tags: lua

I'm creating a hidden loadstring function. I turned the string, 'loadstring' into bytes (each character is in a different variable)

Example:

```
local a = 'loadstring'
ab = a:byte(1,1)
ac = a:byte(2,2)
```

And then I did a `tonumber()` with all of the individual variables.

Example:

```
ab = tonumber(ab)
ac = tonumber(ac)
```

And then I put it in another variable (all individual) stored into a `string.char()` format like this:

Example:

```
ab = string.char(ab)
ac = string.char(ac)
```

Which I was able to successfully accomplish, but I noticed that I don't know how to compile all of the `string.char()` variables. I can only think of using `..` and what I'm trying to get at is that I want to turn this string value into a callable function, like the previous `loadstring`

Example:

```
-- Converting my string 'loadstring' to loadstring (string to function)
loadstring("print'test'")()
```

So yes, if anyone can help me, that'll be great.

My code:

```
a = "108"
b = "111"
c = "97"
d = "100"
e = "115"
f = "116"
g = "114"
h = "105"
i = "110"
j = "103"

a = tonumber(a)
b = tonumber(b)
c = tonumber(c)
d = tonumber(d)
e = tonumber(e)
f = tonumber(f)
g = tonumber(g)
h = tonumber(h)
i = tonumber(i)
j = tonumber(j)

a = string.char(a)
b = string.char(b)
c = string.char(c)
d = string.char(d)
e = string.char(e)
f = string.char(f)
g = string.char(g)
h = string.char(h)
i = string.char(i)
j = string.char(j)

a = a..b..c..d..e..f..g..h..i..j

return a
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden loadstring function"? Are you trying to make a sandbox with a "backdoor" that allows you to loadstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use escape() and unescape() functions to simply hiding the function name,
  and call the function itself as an element of the global table _G:

```
function escape (s)
      local s = string.gsub(s or '', '.', function (a)  return string.format("%%%02X", string.byte(a))   end)
      return s
 end

function unescape (s)
     local  s = string.gsub(s or '', "%%(%x%x)", function (x) return string.char(tonumber(x, 16)) end)
     return s
end

local  f = "loadstring"

print(escape(f))   -- %6C%6F%61%64%73%74%72%69%6E%67

-- using
local strcode = unescape("%6C%6F%61%64%73%74%72%69%6E%67")   -- "loadstring"
_G[strcode] ("print('test')")()   -- test
```

Comment: @LuaTutoring: Note: This will still require that `loadstring` is visible and globally accessible.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was able to make it so loadstring wasn't visible. Thanks for the notice, I had to check.

Comment: @LuaTutoring: I'm curious: how did you do that and still allow `_G["loadstring"]` to work?

Comment: @LuaTutoring: I'm sorry, but I can't actually read that. Can you convert it into something legible? The important part is where you remove `loadstring` from the global table (thus preventing `loadstring(...)` from working) while still allowing `_G["loadstring"](...)` to work.

Comment: @LuaTutoring: As expected, if I stick `loadstring(a)()` at the end of that blob of code... it works just fine. You have hidden nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyways @NicolBolas our conversation is ending.